# AS3 font embed height issue

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts

This is probably the weirdest font embed problem I've had in years...

I'm using Flash CC. Whenever I use an embed font I get this weird result.

[image: problem]

On the left I'm using a system font without embed, on the right I just switch to an embedded font in the library. Nothing else changes. I'm doing everything by code.

The height of the `TextField` and the `textHeight` property changes, depending on if I use an embedded font or not. It doesn't matter what font I embed, I have tried many different fonts with the exact same result.

[image]

I have tried changing the `leading` property in the `TextFormat` object, but there's always some sort of padding at the top of the `textField`.

Anyone has any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Well it seems this is a Flash CC bug... http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1235461

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in Flash CC confirmed by Adobe.

Only solution [as suggested by Adobe](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5476157#5476157) until they fix the bug, is to create a textfield that uses the embedded font via the IDE. Put it on the stage, and hide it.

My client will be very happy.